# when restore down the browser, the position of div changed according to scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

when i tried to restore down the browser or (resize it), the position of div changed,  to see the original position of div i should scroll bar to the top of page if i scroll down the div will moves up .. i just want one thing, i don't want this div moves in all cases ?
answers would be appreciated. Thanks.

html

```
    <div id="socialText"></div>
```

css

```
    #socialText{
    background:url(../images/....) no-repeat;
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    bottom:40px;
    right:50px;
    position:fixed;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    display:none;
    }
```

jquery

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
    $('html').css('overflow','auto');
    });



    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
    $('#facebook')
    .mouseover(function() {
    $('#socialText').show().css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
    $('#socialText').hide().css('backgroundPosition', '0 25px');
    })
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
    $('#twitter')
    .mouseover(function() {
    $('#socialText').show().css('backgroundPosition', '0 -28px');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
    $('#socialText').hide().css('backgroundPosition', '0 25px');
    })
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
    $('#google')
    .mouseover(function() {
    $('#socialText').show().css('backgroundPosition', '0 -57px');
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
    $('#socialText').hide().css('backgroundPosition', '0 25px');
    })
    });
```

Comment: try deleting `position:fixed;` from your css

Comment: i tried, nothing happened

Comment: Try deleting `position:absolute;` instead

Comment: Try setting the position from LEFT instead of RIGHT so, scrollbar or not, you'll end up at the same place.